# IDA Pro: unknown warnings

Tags: ida, idapython

I am using IDA pro to analyze an old nginx binary. I am getting following warnings which I have never seen before. Does anyone have an idea about these warnings?

```
IDA is analysing the input file...
You may start to explore the input file right now.
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'statfs64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'statfs64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'statfs64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'statfs64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'statfs64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'statfs64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
failed to add structure type 'stat64': name is already used
```

I can send you nginx binary if required. And the binary is compiled using a custom version of llvm. I am using IDA Pro 7.5 and an IDAPython script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message shows that you, or a script you run, is trying to create a struct with a name that already exists.

Common IDAPython analysis scripts try to define known struct types found in the disassembled code by, for example, known function signatures/symbols.

This can be done by calling `AddStrucEx` function.

Scripts don't always check whether the struct is already defined before trying to add it - resulting in this error.

`stat64` is a standard Linux structure and variables of that type are most likely used many times in the code.

Comment: do you know how to avoid this/ or is it fine if I just ignore it (without consequences)?

Comment: You can safely ignore these warnings. If you want a "cleaner" run, add a check to the script: Before calling `AddStrucEx`,  do seomething like:`struct_id = idc.GetStrucIdByName(name)`. If the struct does not exist, `struct_id` would be `idc.BADADDR`.